# Keplerian orbital elements of a binary system: computing the eccentricity vector and angular momentum vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, binary-stars

I have been given a binary system and know a few of the keplerian orbital elements such as `semi-major axis,  inclination with respect to the a reference direction (in this case the x-direction), argument of pericentre and longitude of ascending node`. I am also given the magnitude of the eccentricity and angular momentum but I am asked to find their directional vectors (in 3D), but from the information that I have I am not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Find the plane in which the orbits of the two bodies lie. The angular momentum vector is then perpendicular to this plane (use the right-hand rule to determine whether it points "up" or "down"). And the eccentricity vector lies within the orbital plane and points in the direction from apoapsis to periapsis of either orbit. See the Wikipedia articles on [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) and [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem is that I do not know which plane the orbit lies as I am not given the position of the binary objects. The tricky thing is that I have only been given the keplerian orbit elements (just not the direction of the eccentricity)